# cisco N9K-C93180LC-EX port configuration

Tags: cisco-nexus

i have a N9K-C93180LC-EX and refering to the cisco website it is showing that this device support "
Nexus 9K Fixed with up to 32p 40/50G QSFP+ or up to 18p 100G QSFP28" i want to know can i conifgure 10x port to working as 100g and 14x port as 40g/50g or 10g using breakout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Cisco Nexus 93180LC-EX Switch is the industry’s first 50-Gbps-capable 1RU switch that supports 3.6 Tbps of bandwidth and over 2.6 bpps across up to 32 fixed 40- and 50-Gbps QSFP+ ports or up to 18 fixed 100-Gbps ports (Figure 3). The switch can support up to 72 10-Gbps ports using breakout cables. A variety of flexible port configurations are supported using templates.

That description from the Cisco data sheet indicates it is flexible enough to support a variety of mixed interface configurations but is constrained to certain templates. [This link shows how those templates work.](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/hw/n93180lcex_hig/guide/b_c93180lcex_nxos_mode_hardware_install_guide/b_c93180lcex_nxos_mode_hardware_install_guide_chapter_01011.html) Basically you have to configure the ports in specific pairs of vertically aligned ports and even numbers. So your design of 10 at 100 gig and 14 at a lower speed might be supported, yes.